# USB to VGA connector

Tags: usb, connector, vga

What is the connections for a USB-VGA connector? Any resistor or capacitor needed?

I couldn't not find any diagrams on the net.

Comment: You couldn't find any diagrams because it's not something you can build with a "resistor or capacitor". If you need one, buy one.

Answer (score 1):

USB and VGA are not just different plugs. The data streams are encoded entirely differently. To convert from one to the other would require some substantial additional circuitry, probably involving an FPGA/ASIC at the minimum.

Comment: There are a plethora of available adapters that take USB from a host PC and provide VGA style video signalling to run a monitor. Almost all the ones that have decent and reliable drives use special USB video controller ASICs from a company called DisplayLink. http://www.displaylink.com/